# Why can't I use a next statement in a while loop?

Tags: r, data-science

```
    ctr <- 1
while(ctr <=7){
  if(ctr%%5==0){
    break
  }
  print(paste("ctr is set to", ctr))
  ctr <- ctr+1
}
```

the output I get is

```
[1] "ctr is set to 1"
[1] "ctr is set to 2"
[1] "ctr is set to 3"
[1] "ctr is set to 4"
```

but when I try to *replace break with next*, it doesn't work .

Comment: What do you mean by *it doesn't work*? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: `break` will break out of the loop altogether and go to the next statement, while `next` will only go to the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: I expect to get the answer "Ctr is set to 6" and "Ctr is set to 7" , and then it ends it there, since my limited understanding says next skips the current iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You dont increment ctr if you just swap `break` for `next` so it loops forever at a value of 5. You need to put `ctr <- ctr+1` before the next as well

Comment: How is it that it works when I use break?

Comment: Because 'break' stops the entire loop completely, nothing else needs to happen. 

'next' tells the loop to stop this iteration and carry on, so it stops inside the if statement, doesn't do the print or the +1, and then it loops again, forever because each time it loops, it will hit the if statement again as ctl is always 5. ctl will never be >=7. break doesn't care if because it stops the loop totally, doesn't just skip one go-around